# vertical-align: middle moves element the wrong direction but vertical-align: top works as expected

Tags: css

I have three inline block elements inside a a container div.

The HTML looks like this:

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="field">Text</div>
   <div class="field">Text</div>
   <div class="arrow"></div>
</div>
```

The CSS looks like this:

```
.container {
    padding: 10px; 
    border: solid 1px #e5e5e5;
    border-radius: 3px;
    background-color: white;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-size: 0;
}

.field {
    font-size: 16px;
    display: inline-block;
}

.arrow {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 0; 
    height: 0; 
    border-left: 5px solid transparent;
    border-right: 5px solid transparent;
    border-top: 5px solid #f00;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

I can't see anything wrong with this HTML/CSS, but the arrow does not appear in the middle of the container. Instead, the arrow is near the bottom of the container. Also, when I unset the `vertical-align: middle` property, the arrow moves farther up in the div, which is weird. If I set `vertical-align: top` then the arrow does go to the top of the div. Any idea why this is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Default `vertical-align` is `baseline`.  This will operate differently than true middle when paired with middle. Try setting all three to middle.

```css
.container {
    padding: 10px; 
    border: solid 1px #e5e5e5;
    border-radius: 3px;
    background-color: white;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-size: 0;
}

.field {
    font-size: 16px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.arrow {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 0; 
    height: 0; 
    border-left: 5px solid transparent;
    border-right: 5px solid transparent;
    border-top: 5px solid #f00;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
   <div class="field">Text</div>
   <div class="field">Text</div>
   <div class="arrow"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Good to know. Thanks for the quick answer.

Answer (score 0):

Change `.arrow` from `inline-block` to `inline`

https://jsfiddle.net/aznfacLe/